# How can I inject IPrincipal using TinyIoC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, tinyioc

This line:

```
container.Register<IPrincipal>().UsingConstructor(() => HttpContext.Current.User);
```

throws the following exception:

> Cannot register type System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal - abstract
>   classes or interfaces are not valid implementation types for
>   SingletonFactory.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Tss.Rhnncp.DietPlanner.Bootstap.TinyIoCRegistrationTypeException:
>   Cannot register type System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal - abstract
>   classes or interfaces are not valid implementation types for
>   SingletonFactory.

Source Error:

```
Line 2663: throw new TinyIoCRegistrationTypeException(registerImplementation, "SingletonFactory");
Line 2664:
Line 2665:  if (!IsValidAssignment(registerType, registerImplementation))
Line 2666:      throw new TinyIoCRegistrationTypeException(registerImplementation, "SingletonFactory");
Line 2667:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with TinyIoc, but I expect you need something like this:

```
container.Register<IPrincipal>(() => HttpContext.Current.User);
```

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks for your reply. I've tried this and got an error indicating that 'Argument type "lambda expression" is not assignable to parameter type "IPrincipal"'